# Extracting Text (Capital Letter)

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I download bank transaction history and would like to extract the name of customers which is located at the end of the Description line. Some lines have one or two words preceding the names of the customer. How can I extract the all capitalize Names.

I also need to extract the amount transferred from text and convert it into numbers.

```
DESCRIPTION                                                     AMOUNT
TRSF E-BANKING DB 2701/FTSCY/WS95051 12000.00 JAMES BOND        12,000.00 DB
TRSF E-BANKING CR 2701/FTSCY/WS95051 10000.00 deposit CHRISTINE 10,000.00 CR
TRSF E-BANKING CR 2701/FTSCY/WS95051 25025.00 AMANDA B GREEN    25,025.00 CR
TRSF E-BANKING CR 2701/FTSCY/WS95051 5000.00 msn1888 JOSH BROWN  5,000.00 CR
TRSF E-BANKING CR 2701/FTSCY/WS95051 1000.00 topup CHRISTINE     1,000.00 CR
```

Result:

```
CUSTOMER      TRANSFER
JAMES BOND    12,000
CHRISTINE     10,000
AMAND B GREEN 25,025
JOSH BROWN     5,000
CHRISTINE      1,000
TOTAL         53,025
```

Comment: Hello ! It is not entirely clear how your data is formatted, it looks like you have two column headers, but maybe 7 different columns. I suspect there is one column with a lot of space delimited data in it, so actually only two columns. Could you please edit your question to confirm the layout of this data, and what methods you have tried or attempted so far, so we can better assist you?

Comment: I'd suggest to use regular expression add-in, it's free and provides you the most straightforward solution. However to give more specific help, I need to have the answer for Jonno's question in his comment

Comment: I have only 2 columns, the first column DESCRIPTION has a long delimited data in it. While the second column AMOUNT is text with DB/CR at the end of the text (such as 12,000.00 DB).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using Macros / VBA :

```
Public Function extract_name(transaction As String)
    Dim WordArray() As String
    WordArray() = Split(transaction, " ")
    firstName = WordArray(5)
    extract_name = firstName
    extract_name_uc = UCase(extract_name)
    If extract_name = extract_name_uc Then
        topBound = 5
    Else
        topBound = 6
    End If
    extract_name = ""
    For i = topBound To UBound(WordArray)
        tempValue = WordArray(i)
        If IsNumeric(tempValue) Then
            i = UBound(WordArray)
        Else
            extract_name = extract_name & " " & tempValue
        End If
    Next i
    extract_name = Trim(extract_name)
End Function

Public Function extract_amount(transaction As String)
    Dim WordArray() As String
    WordArray() = Split(transaction, " ")
    extract_amount = WordArray(UBound(WordArray) - 1)
End Function
```

There are two functions `extract_name`and `extract_amount`.

Open VBA with ALT+ F11, insert a module under *ThisWorkbook* and paste the code on the right side.

Supposing that `TRSF E-BANKING DB 2701/FTSCY/WS95051 12000.00 JAMES BOND    12,000.00 DB` is in cell *A2* then:

*B2* `=extract_name(A2)` and *C2* `=extract_amount(A2)`.

Comment: Is there any reason why you didn't do the same `-1` trick from `extract_amount` in `extract_name`??  `extract_name = WordArray(-2)`

Comment: The position of the amount is always the same.  The position of the name is not  the same for each row and besides of that sometimes it uses one field and other times two or three fields.

Comment: I have tried the macros but it failed. Can you please make it in a downloadable excel file? Thanks

Comment: @harimin You can download it from `http://www.filedropper.com/extract_1` . Remember that when you open the file Excel will ask for permission to execute macros.

Comment: I have downloaded the file but as I have tried before, I still couldn't run the macro. If you don't mind, please follow the link to see the original data I copy to your files https://filedropper.com/filemanager/public.php?service=files&t=21ea9d05d78e797de056a1139f659d29

Comment: @harimin i uploaded a modification in http://www.filedropper.com/extractnew. Check carefully the formulas in cells `C6:E6`. They reference to the macros.

Comment: I can run the macro now :D  The sample I sent previously contained edited false data. But when I copied to my real data, the extract_name macro didn't work properly. I cannot figure out why. Please see file attach, thanks. http://www.filedropper.com/bca

Comment: @harimin I uploaded the modification to make it work. http://www.filedropper.com/bca2

Comment: @jcbermu Wow, it works perfectly now! Many thanks for your great help :D